# Did key-wrap modes see actual use?

Tags: protocol-design, key-wrap

Is there an IETF standard-track protocol have IANA-registered IDs for deterministic authenticated encryption yet? If not, what's preventing their adoption? What changes to protocols will DAEs likely require?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, this has become a considerably better question now. I guess it's mainly the lack of a "sponsor" if no ID is assigned by the IETF. If nobody takes the initiative, then nothing happens.

Comment: By the way, I've used SIV mode once to wrap an asymmetric key. Does that make me a hero? ;)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I guess you're using private-use IDs even if it's an IETF standard-track protocol am I right? (Shall we move to chat?)

Comment: Why do you need registered IDs to see evidence of use?  Do registered IDs serve any purpose in modern protocols like WireGuard that work as a unit, rather than by handing a pile of cryptographic acronym soup to uninformed users to assemble like tinker toys?

Comment: In particular, usually if a family of protocols is already secure when instantiated a mere (perhaps nonce-based or randomized) AEAD, there is never any reason to substitute a DAE—there is no security advantage, but there is a performance cost.  So DAE is really relevant only to _new_ protocols that are _not_ adequately served by AEAD, and in new protocols it would be foolish to repeat the design mistake of fine-grained ‘algorithm agility’ that permeated the dark ages of cryptography engineering in the '90s and left us with cobwebby registries of mouldering acronym soup.

Comment: I've never understood algorithm agility in the first place. If there is an advantageous method then generally you cannot substitute the old with the new without changing the way things are handled. I'd prefer to write code for one or the other even if that means some repetition on the higher level; that's better than code riddled with `if` statements.

Comment: @DannyNiu If we move to chat we need 7 messages to let it survive (this is #7, so we're getting there). Why do you think I need an ID to use the algorithm? If I know which algorithm to use (e.g. by using a higher level version number up front, if any number at all) then I don't need to identify the algorithm.